# How can I save queries using broadcastreceiver for Android?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I want to save the history of queries made between my application and my database using a broadcastreceiver . How can I do that?

Comment: is your database local ?

Comment: yes my database is local

Comment: so why do you want to use broadcast receiver to save history of queries ?

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the fact that this task is too weird, in order to do that you need to create a custom `BroadcastRicever` ,

```
public class DatabaseRecever extends BroadcastReceiver {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                if (intent.getAction().equals("database")) {
                   saveLogs();
                }
            }
    }
and
```

and send a `sendBroadcast` intent every time you communicate with your local database and then in your receiver save the log you want